# Identify a horror movie with scene of bat-creatures escaping from man's stomach?

Tags: story-identification, horror

Someone asked my wife this question but I'm not sure I have an answer?

"Hey Tara, I'd like to engage your enormous knowledge of horror films, please!
 This is a film, possibly made sometime in the 80's-ish, where in one scene a guy eats a burger and then falls to the floor, his stomach opens and all these horrible little batlike creatures come flying out!
 A friend is being driven nuts, trying to remember!!!
 Thanks xxx"

Comment: Also posted at https://getsatisfaction.com/imdb/topics/horror-a-guy-eating-a-bit-of-a-burger-maybe-he-a-mechanic-then-he-lays-on-his-back-his

Comment: I understand the DVs for lack of detail, but is there actually a rule against asking a question on Stack AND another site at the same time?

Comment: it may not be a network-wide rule but it's _very_ highly frowned upon, and many stacks, by consensus, will close cross-posts when found.

Comment: I think it's usually more frowned upon putting it on multiple Stack Exchange sites. I was mainly posting the link because I'd run into it with my Google searches and that way, if it gets an answer there, maybe someone will notice and post it here. I have not actually downvoted the question, but I dislike secondhand queries like these because they so seldom actually get answered, and it's impossible to get more details.

Comment: Hi folks, sorry 1st time user, have I dine something wrong?

Comment: the core question, imo, is fine. It's just how it is presented. Focus less on the anecdote of your wife and the friend and all that stuff that nobody other than you will ever care about or search for. Simply list all the identifying aspects of the film you have (language, black and white or color, originating country, etc....) and you may have better luck. Look at some of the existing identification questions posted to the right for good examples

Comment: @JoeMorrison - Hey Joe.  Welcome to the site.  You haven't done anything terribly wrong, but the site is community moderated and sometimes how we should handle things can get a little tangled (I didn't know what is being mentioned above, honestly).  You probably have included just enough detail to work with (the scene sounds unique-ish, but could fit *Spaceballs* of all things, stomach-bursters have been done lots), but if there's anything else to add (like when and where it was seen, which can narrow it down a lot, 80s is just kind of a guess that could be wrong), it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's Lobster Man from Mars - quite weird example of THAT kind of moovies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobster_Man_from_Mars

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please [edit] in some points as to why you think this is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185651/guy-eats-something-and-a-creature-comes-out-of-his-belly-and-flies-away (also a good place to harvest details from).