# Guy eats something and a creature comes out of his belly and flies away

Tags: story-identification, movie

This scene has bugged me for years:

- It's night time IIRC
- Guy is outside, leaning against a car, probably a parking lot
- He eats something, most likely a burger/sandwich
- Feels something strange, reaches his hand for his belly
- His hand is wet with blood or green goo IIRC
- Creature comes out and flies away
- He watches as it flies away
- IIRC there's no panic, he doesn't freak out
- Most likely an American production
- Watched on TV, in the 90's, could be older though

This is probably my memory playing tricks on me, but the movie may end with a old man and a boy watching a movie in an old cinema or something.

I posted this same question years ago on a website focused on horror movie and it got 1 comment saying they were looking for the same scene. But the website is long gone (archive https://web.archive.org/web/20120803214930/best-horror-movies.com/little-monster-comes-out-of-guys-tummy-and-flies-away.html)

Comment: I wonder if this is from Fringe... Do you happen to remember if it was a movie, TV show, or mini-series?

Comment: Most likely a movie, but expanding the scope, I considered the possibility of being part of an anthology like Creepshow or tv series like "Are you afraid of the dark?"
I'm currently looking through a list of movies by year, starting from the 1980, so far nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Lobster man From Mars* (1989)

Around the 26 minutes mark this scene comes up.
It's not exactly outdoors. It happens inside a garage while the doors are open.
The guy, a small town mechanic, is leaning against the garage's work table when he eats the hamburger.

Regarding the old man and boy watching the movie, the [IMDB movie summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097768/plotsummary#plot-summaries-content) says:

> Young film student tries to sell his weird movie to a desperate film producer who is in need of a tax write-off. The producer screens the film "Lobster Man From Mars". What follows is one of the most bizarre and funny film within-a-film sendups: Mars suffers from an air leakage, and send the dreaded Lobster Man to Earth to steal its air. The plot is foiled by a mad scientist, a girl, and an army colonel. The producer buys the movie, but it makes a huge profit and the producer is sent to jail, with the film student taking his place as the studio hot shot

### Trailer